# Elasticsearch: What is the difference between a match and a term in a filter?

Tags: elasticsearch

I was following an ES tutorial, and at some point I wrote a query using `term` in the filter instead the recommended solution using `match`. My understanding is that `match` was used in the query part to get scoring, while `term` was used in the `filter` part to just remove hits before enter the query part. To my surprise `match` also works in the `filter` part.

What is the difference between:

```
GET blogs/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "match": {
          "category.keyword": "News"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and:

```
GET blogs/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "category.keyword": "News"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Both returns the same hits, and the score is 0 for all hits.

What is the behaviour or `match` in a filter clause? I would expect it to yield some score, but it does not.

What I thought:

- `term` : does not analyze either the parameter or the field, and it is a `yes/no` scenario.
- `match` : analyzes parameter and field and calculates a score of how good they match.

But when using `match` against a `keyword` in the `filter` part of the query, how does it behave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `match` query is a high-level query that resorts to using a `term` query if it needs to.

Scoring has nothing to do with using `match` instead of `term`. Scoring kicks in when you use [`bool/must/should` instead of `bool/filter`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html).

Here is how the `match` query works:

First, it checks the type of the field.

- If it's a `text` field then the value will be analyzed, either with the analyzer specified in the query (if any), or with the search- or index-time analyzer specified in the mapping.
- If it's a `keyword` field (like in your case), then the input is not analyzed and taken "as is"

Since you're using the `match` query on a `keyword` field and your input is a single term, nothing is analyzed and the `match` query resorts to using a `term` query underneath. This is why you're seeing the same results.

In general, it's always best to use a `match` query as it is smart enough to know what to do given the field you're querying and the input data you're searching for.

You can read more about the difference between the two [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/term-vs-full-text.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If in the first query, I match against `category` (which is analyzed) instead `category.keyword`, how will it behave? Just as a `term` because in `filter` the score does not matter?

Comment: No, it you `match` against `category` which is analyzed, then `News` will be analyzed, too, and the `category` field will be matched with `news` (standard analyzer). No scoring since you're in a `bool/filter` query.

Comment: Just one more question :D As you said, there is no scoring because it is in a bool/filter query. But how is decided if a document passes or not the filter ? Because mach over an analyzed field will yield a score of how good it matches, right?

Comment: A document can match even if there is no scoring, if the `category` fields contains `news` and you're searching for `news` then it's a match.

Comment: And if it contains "nows" or "new"?

Comment: Then it wouldn't match (unless you leverage [fuzziness](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#fuzziness)), `term` wouldn't match either. It's easy to try it out